# The best way to check if a given string contains only a kind of character

Tags: python, algorithm

To be specific, if I have string a: `a = "uuuuuuuuuuuuuiuuuuu"` and string b: `b = "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu"` and I want to check if the given string only contains one kind of character. In the first string, it contains another char called i, so it will return false. The string b it has only one kind, so it will return true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the string to a set and look at its length:

```
a = "uuuuuuuuuuuuuiuuuuu"
print(len(set(a)) == 1)
# False

b = "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu"
print(len(set(b)) == 1)
#True
```